# Access Tokens - Generating Authorization Code

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am following the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens

However, it does not generate the authorization code after replacing all placeholders below. The message I get on Postman is as follows: When I attempt on the browser nothing is returned.

```
<noscript>
        <div id="no_js">
            <div class="error_container">
                <div>
                    <h1>We can't sign you in</h1>
                    <p>Your browser is currently set to block JavaScript. You need to allow JavaScript to use this
                        service.</p>
                    <p>To learn how to allow JavaScript or to find out whether your browser supports JavaScript, check
                        the online help in your web browser.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </noscript>

GET https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<application-ID>
&nonce=anyRandomValue
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=https://<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/api/read
&response_type=code
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you make the below request using browser by Seting the Scope to `scope=https%3A%2F%2Fcontoso.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fread%20openid%20offline_access` and by updating the tenant and client id

```
GET https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<application-ID>
&nonce=anyRandomValue
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fcontoso.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fread%20openid%20offline_access
&response_type=code
```

You will receive the response with the authorization code as below in the URL

```
https://jwt.ms/?code=eyJraWQiOiJjcGltY29yZV8wOTI1MjAxNSIsInZlciI6IjEuMC...
```

[image]

After successfully receiving the authorization code in the above response URL copy the code value and make the post request to get an access token

```
POST <tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: <tenant-name>.b2clogin.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=<application-ID>
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fcontoso.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fread%20openid%20offline_access
&code=eyJraWQiOiJjcGltY29yZV8wOTI1MjAxNSIsInZlciI6IjEuMC...
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&client_secret=2hMG2-_:y12n10vwH...
```

[image]
Replace the code with the authorization code which you received in the responce of first request and use the client_secret of Client application.

Comment: This does not answer my question as you have just quoted the rest of the documentation I have raised the query on

Comment: I have updated my answer with the request and response screenshots. Please check the scope value and the request responce `code value` in the Url not in the html body. For the initial authentication get request you can call it from broswer and while getting the access token post request try with tools like postman.

Comment: @DavidOnyango, the point is, what your trying to do is *not* possible. you **have** to request an authorization code via the web browser, it is supposed to be an interactive request. The only way is to follow exactly what this answer and the doc states.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the documented process works only when you open the browser in private mode to generate authorization code in my case